# Change input value but not change result in PhpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have got a problem with PHPExcel as below function

```
function Test($a, $b) {

    //  Create a new PHPExcel object with a single sheet
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('B2',$a);
    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('B3',$b);
    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('C4',"=B2+B3");
    $C4 = $activeSheet ->getCell('C4')->getCalculatedValue();

    echo "C4:$C4<br/>";
}
```

Finally, I call this function

```
Test(10, 20);
Test(40, 70);
Test(30, 80);
```

but, result is

```
C4:30
C4:30
C4:30
```

Why **getCalculatedValue()** DOESN'T change result? It seems like this function only gets the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the result, but for performance reasons the calculation engine caches the result of a formula calculation once it's been calculated. If you want to change the underlying data, you have to flush that cache before requesting the calculated value again:

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->clearCalculationCache();
```

or

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::flushInstance();
```

You can also change this default behaviour - so that results are not cached at all - before issuing any other requests to the calculation engine:

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->setCalculationCacheEnabled(FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks your support. I tried again and results are not cached. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use phpExcel don't need you it. You can only do it:

set header once.

`$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();`

Then use it

`function Test($a, $b) {

```
$activeSheet->SetCellValue('B2',$a);
$activeSheet->SetCellValue('B3',$b);
$activeSheet->SetCellValue('C4',"=B2+B3");
```

}`

ad set you value `Test(10, 30);`

if you set coll and don't change cell, overwrite. If you need do a list

```
function Test($a, $b) {
$i++;
    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('B2',$a);
    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('B3',$b);
    $activeSheet->SetCellValue('C'.$i,"=B2+B3");

}
```

and set you value `Test(10, 30);`

then output `40`